# Cannot close VSCode terminal using CTRL + `

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can open terminal window by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>, but I can't close it by <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>.

I have deleted all things in keybindings.json, so maybe there is no custom keymap.

If I click this symbol:

[image]

and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>, it only shows:

[image].

If I press <kbd>`</kbd>, it shows:

[image]

Comment: Does CTRL + J work?